# jdiameter-ha-* ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, restcomm

I'm attempting introduce high availability mode (via JBoss Cache) in my server implementation (essentially an expanded version of the example server) by configuring my Maven project to use `jdiameter-ha-api` and `jdiameter-ha-impl` dependencies instead of `jdiameter-api` and `jdiameter-impl`, in addition to adding the following extensions to `jdiameter-config.xml`:

```
<Extensions>
    <SessionDatasource value="org.mobicents.diameter.impl.ha.data.ReplicatedSessionDatasource"/>
    <TimerFacility value="org.mobicents.diameter.impl.ha.timer.ReplicatedTimerFacilityImpl"/>
</Extensions>
```

Now, when I run the server from Eclipse, it works fine, i.e. it start up in clustered mode (w/ JBoss Cache), however, when I attempt to run the `jar` produced by `mvn install`, it throws the following error:

```
2018-10-11 18:24:13,899 - (-)(-)(-)(-)(-) Starting Mobicents DIAMETER Stack v1.7.0-SNAPSHOT (-)(-)(-)(-)(-)
2018-10-11 18:24:13,959 - Failure creating stack 'Server'
org.jdiameter.api.InternalException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at org.jdiameter.client.impl.StackImpl.init(StackImpl.java:135)
  at com.company.charging.diameter.ocf.utilities.StackCreator.<init>(StackCreator.java:37)
  at com.company.charging.diameter.ocf.utilities.StackCreator.<init>(StackCreator.java:71)
  at com.company.charging.diameter.ocf.server.Ocf.<init>(Ocf.java:187)
  at com.company.charging.diameter.ocf.server.Ocf.main(Ocf.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
  at org.jdiameter.client.impl.StackImpl.init(StackImpl.java:129)
  ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mobicents.diameter.impl.ha.timer.ReplicatedTimerFacilityImpl
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
  at org.jdiameter.client.impl.helpers.AssemblerImpl.fill(AssemblerImpl.java:139)
  at org.jdiameter.client.impl.helpers.AssemblerImpl.<init>(AssemblerImpl.java:91)
  ... 9 more
```

Given that it starts up in Eclipse just fine, I'm assuming my POM file isn't managing dependencies properly, so that the final `jar` is missing these classes. Here's the relevant portion of my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mobicents.diameter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdiameter-ha-api</artifactId>
    <version>${restcomm.diameter.jdiameter.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mobicents.diameter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdiameter-ha-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${restcomm.diameter.jdiameter.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mobicents.diameter</groupId>
    <artifactId>restcomm-diameter-mux-jar</artifactId>
    <version>${restcomm.diameter.mux.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```